# Expected value of maximum likelihood estimator of a Bernoulli random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, parameter-estimation

While reading the text from Keith H. Thompson on the [Estimation of the Proportion of Vectors in a Natural Population of Insects](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2527902?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), I came across the following part where I don't understand everything.

---

Let $p$ be the proportion of viruliferous insects and $h(p) = (1-p)^k$ where $k$ is the number of insects on each plant, a Bernoulli random variable $X$ may be defined with probability function 
$$b[x;p,k] = [h(p)]^x[1-h(p)]^{1-x}$$
such that $X = 1$ if a plant is not infected and $X = 0$ if a plant is infected. In $n$ trials ($n$ plants are tested), the maximum likelihood estimators of $h(p)$ and $p$ are obtained from the likelihood function $L = \prod_{i=1}^n b[x_i; p, k]$ as 
$$\hat{h}(p) = \frac{\sum X_i}{n}$$
and
$$\hat{p} = 1 - \left[ \frac{\sum X_i}{n} \right]^{1/k}$$
respectively.
[...] and $\hat{p}$ is a biased estimator of $p$ with mean
$$E(\hat{p}) = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^n \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{1/k} \binom{n}{i}[(1-p)^k]^i[1-(1-p)^k]^{n-i}.$$
[...]
As $n$ approaches infinity, the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{p}$ is distributed asymptotically normally and converges in probability to $p$. $\hat{p}$ is also asymptotically efficient, and its asymptotic variance is determined as
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} V(\hat{p}) = \frac{1}{nE\left[ \frac{ \partial \log b(x; p, k)}{\partial p}\right]^2}.$$

---

I never had a class on statistics, so I am unfamiliar with the notions of estimators, but I am a math student so I am familiar with the notions of expectancy, variance, and laws.

I could find some references on how to derive $\hat{h}(p)$ and we derive $\hat{p}$ from $\hat{h}(p)$ so my questions are the following:

1. I could not derive $E(\hat{p})$, so how is this done?
2. Is $\hat{p}$ is distributed asymptotically normally because of the central limit theorem?
3. Is the asymptotic variance derived from a specific formula?

Thanks for any answer

Comment: For 1) Once you derive $\hat{p}$,  you should have a function that involves random variables $X_i$. You apply expectation operator to this function. For 2) the answer is yes, although you can also show that the log-likelihood function becomes quadratic (equivalent statement). 3) This is also due to CLT and that the (negative) curvature of the log-likelihood is the inverse of the standard error squared when it is quadratic.

Comment: For 1, linearity of expectation gives $E(\hat{p})=1-(n^{-1/k})E(V^{1/k})$, where $V=\sum X_i$ is a $binomial(n,(1-p)^k)$ random variable. You understand expectation, and the formula he gives simply plugs in the standard defining formula for the expectation of $V^{1/k}$. For 2 and 3 we usually invoke standard theorems giving the asymptotic normality and efficiency (in typical situations) of the maximum likelihood estimator, but if you're asking why they hold, proofs are readily available on google if you're question is why they hold.

Comment: Thanks guys, got it right :)